# First order logic of complex quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, foundations

Suppose we describe quantum theory through the København interpretation, that is, through unitary linear algebra of complex Hilbert spaces.

Can quantum theory in this description (the part that matters to Physics) be totally captured by the (true statements of the) first order theory of fields about $\mathbb{C}$ ?

In other words: are there statements which are not provable in the first order theory of fields about $\mathbb{C}$ which are fundamental to quantum theory ?

Comment: I don't think unitary linear algebra of complex Hilbert spaces is what distinguishes the Copenhagen interpretation.

Comment: Can you give some examples of statements not provable in the first order theory of fields about  $\mathbb{C}$, in particular statements you think might be relevant for quantum mechanics? My (*very* naive) understanding is that first-order logic is sufficient for the "standard" set theory (eg the ZFC axioms) that underlies linear algebra and complex analysis.

Comment: @Andrew: that is precisely my question (and I will edit it accordingly). Thanks ! THC

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic): "No first-order theory, however, has the strength to uniquely describe a structure with an infinite domain, such as the natural numbers or the real line." At least at a mathematical level, I think you need both to deal with quantum mechanics. For example, the domain of the 1d harmonic oscillator in position space is the real line and the eigenvalues are labeled by all natural numbers.

Comment: @LucasBaldo : what distinguishes it according to you ?